# Where should I put the Apache headers?

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2, security, letsencrypt

I have an 18.04 Ubuntu server with a Drupal 8 site that is certified by Let's Encrypt.

```
# sudo certbot --apache -d mydomaine.com -d www.mydomaine.com  --rsa-key-size 4096
# sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.mydomaine.com-le-ssl.conf
```

Here is the content :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost 00.00.00.000:443 [0000:0000:000:0000::000]:443>

      ServerAdmin contact@mydomaine.com
      ServerName mydomaine.com
      ServerAlias www.mydomaine.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/web/

      <Directory /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/web>
         Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
      </Directory>

      <FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
      </FilesMatch>

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomaine.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomaine.com/privkey.pem

      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
      Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
      Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
      Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
      Header always set X-Download-Options "noopen"
      Header always set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
      Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
      Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure

   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Should I move the Headers in options-ssl-apache ?

```
# sudo nano /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

Here is the content :

```
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

SSLEngine on

# Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

# Add vhost name to log entries:
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common

#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vhost_combined
#LogLevel warn
#ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Always ensure Cookies have "Secure" set (JAH 2012/1)
#Header edit Set-Cookie (?i)^(.*)(;\s*secure)??((\s*;)?(.*)) "$1; Secure$3$4"
```

Comment: Why do you want to move the `Header` statements? Is something not working the way it should? Please edit your question to clarify the issue.

Comment: @zwets not everything works fine but I do not know where their place should be

Comment: Then stick to IT wisdom: if it ain't broke, don't fix it. Note that all that `Include` does is pull in the content of the include file as if it were here. The [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) are very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As result of using `IncludeOptional/Include` directives everything is treated as one big configuration file (`apache2.conf`), so only the tags like as `<VirtualHost>` does have meaning. If you place a directive outside the `<VirtualHost>` tags it will be valid on the server level - for all virtual hosts. If you place a directive inside such tags it will be valid only for the certain virtual host.